# Object Tracking for mouse control

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I am currently making a mouse controller by using object tracking (webcam) and a laser pointer using Python 2.7, OpenCV 3.1, Numpy and Autopy. What would be a faster and more accurate way of detecting laser movement: scanning all of the pixels every frame or using cv2.absdiff() and finding the difference between three frames (frame-1,frame,frame+1)?

Regarding scanning every pixel, I've read elsewhere about the speed of boolean matrices using numpy, but I can't figure out how to both use them or how they work.

Since this is for mouse movement, speed and accuracy are needed.

Comment: "scanning all of the pixels every frame" -- If you mean iterating over the pixels in Python, that's going to be awfully slow. You need to make most use of the numpy and opencv functions that are implemented in C or C++ and often very well optimized. Is the laser spot bright enough that you could reliably pick it up with thresholding of the red channel, and then finding and evaluating the contours in the resulting mask?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a forum; Asking for help and thanking people within your post is discouraged. Please also consider a clearer question statement.